# Matching rails to a server and rack

Tags: rack

I have acquired a number of Gigabyte GS-R22PHL systems, which came without rails. Manuals and website make no mention of rail kits, and Gigabyte is not a huge seller of datacenter hardware, which makes this complicated to figure out.

My rack is an HP 10000 (formerly a Compaq/Digital design with square holes supporting cage nuts), as run of the mill a rack as one can be, but I am stumped with matching a kit of telescoping rails to it and the servers over the Web. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specs](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Enterprise/GPU-Server/GS-R22PHL-rev-10#Specifications) on their website, the Gigabyte Rail Kit part number for this server model is 25HB2-A86100-K0R. I could not find any simple way to order them online though, so you'll probably have to contact your reseller or Gigabyte's sales department directly.

Comment: You are correct - I found the same kit number... but it seems un-findable ten years later.